# Mojave Safari 14.1.2 - css animation svg disappearing during playback

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, macos-mojave

Is someone able to explain a problem in Safari for this simple example:

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/trtrtrr/pen/YzVejva)

The logo-1 class element should animate into position from right to left. On mac it works in Firefox, Chrome and in IE11/win8 in the original bigger piece of code. In Safari during css animation the svg graphics disappears and appears only after animation is done. It only animates correctly if there is an extra dummy sibling to the svg element with a 3d transform applied to it. It needs to be on a lower z-index than the svg or the animation display fails. Ideally the svg element should be the only child of the logo-1 class element.

In the codepen example animation shows correctly for me in Safari only in the first main div that has the extra element under logo-1 element.

Any ideas?

Codepen code:

```css
.logo-1 svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.logo-1-sequence {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 113px;
  height: 134px;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes kf-frame-1-logo-1-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(0.47, 0.47, 1) translate3d(2078px, 20px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale3d(0.47, 0.47, 1) translate3d(1578px, 20px, 0);
  }
}

.logo-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 93px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: kf-frame-1-logo-1-in 0.5s 0.5s both linear 1;
}

.main {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo-1">
    <div class="logo-1-sequence"></div>
    <svg class="logo-1-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="93" height="150" viewBox="0 0 93 150">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo-1">
    <!--         <div class="logo-1-sequence"></div> -->
    <svg class="logo-1-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="93" height="150" viewBox="0 0 93 150">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can reproduce this on Catalina as well. Not specific to Mojave.

Comment: Why did you comment out the `logo-1-sequence` div in the second container? With that div intact the animation works as expected

Comment: Yes. It is commented out to show the discrepancy in the animation results. The logo-1-sequence should not be there. Ideally it should work just with the only child that would be the svg element.Thank you for confirming the issue.

Comment: But you're attaching CSS to that div... Move that css, specifically the `transform` to the outer div and it should work

Comment: Right. As in the original post the sibling element needs to have a 3d transform in order for the animation to work in Safari. It does not work if the svg is the only child or the sibling is not forced to use 3d rendering. I am aware of the workaround. Would like to know why Safari has rendering issues with this simple example.

Comment: That's because a transform will create a new context. This is entirely expected.

Comment: OK. Why would Safari have an issue animating a container with a single svg child where it works in other browsers?

Comment: It looks like for this example in Safari the svg needs to be forced into 3d rendering in order for the parent 3d transform animate correctly. Why would that matter in that browser?

Comment: Browsers, like all software, has bugs. Why is that a mystery?